# Cloning a large svn repository from sourceforge with "git svn clone"

Tags: git, svn, git-svn, sourceforge

I'm trying to clone a [large subversion repository](https://sourceforge.net/p/vice-emu/code/HEAD/tree/) from sourceforge using `git svn clone`. The cloning process periodically gets stuck: SF just stops sending data. Eventually it times out, but it takes *forever*.  After this, it's a cycle of:

- Run `git svn fetch`
- Wait for it to timeout
- Repeat as necessary

Looking at the `git svn` man page, there doesn't appear to be an obvious way to set a timeout for i/o operations.

Is there any way to make this process more efficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's me give you some advice on speeding things up. I just finished running them myself so I'm sure they work. The main trick is to copy Subversion repository to the local filesystem and then run `git svn`.

First, [SourceForge allows to backup repositories using `rsync`](https://sourceforge.net/p/forge/documentation/svn/) (see the last command at the very bottom). So start with

```
rsync -ahPv svn.code.sf.net::p/vice-emu/code vice-emu.svn
```

In a general case where `rsync` access is not available you can use `svnrdump` to dump the repository:

```
svnrdump dump --non-interactive https://svn.code.sf.net/p/vice-emu/code > vice-emu.svndump
```

and then load the dump into a local repository:

```
svnadmin create vice-emu.svn
svnadmin load vice-emu.svn < vice-emu.svndump
```

Either way you can use `git svn` on the local repository:

```
git svn clone file://`pwd`/vice-emu.svn vice-emu
```

And finally yet another trick: [offload the import to Github](https://help.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/importing-source-code-to-github).

My results are: https://github.com/phdru/vice-emu-ghi (Github Importer) and https://github.com/phdru/vice-emu-gitsvn (`rsync` + `git svn` + postprocessing).

PS. If you gonna fork one or both of my results please ping me afterward and I'll remove my temporary repositories. Else I'll remove then soon.

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic. I had no idea it was possible to `rsync` from sourceforge like that! You can go ahead and remove your temporary repos. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can resume the process at the revision that you saw that it was able to pull fine (or say, 100 revisions before that) with -r

```
git svn fetch -r some-revision:HEAD
```

That way you don't restart from scratch.

Comment: I think that's what `git svn fetch` does by default. That is, when I (re-)run `git svn fetch`, it picks up where it left off...but rapidly gets stuck again. At which point I either wait for a timeout or I SIGINT it, then re-run...